# Javascript multiple promises not working with q and request middle

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, request, promise

So this is my dilemma. I have a list of movies, witch I have scraped from a website, then I want to add additional properties to my newly constructed object(json)

Now the omdi api witch I am using supports searching for a movie by title.
Then I make a get request using request and q middlewares. When I receive information from omdb api in the call back I add that data to the object.

Now the next part is where my problem lies. Now I want to return a new Request using data from the previous request. Now I  make an new get Request and return it but then() func isin't returning anything. But I don't seem to realize what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code..

```
var promises = [];
films.forEach(function (film) {
    // Get omdbapi information
    promises.push(HttpService.getContent(configExternal.omodburl + '?t=' + film.title.trim() + '&y=' + film.year + '&plot=true&tomatoes=true&r=json').then(function (data) { 
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        if(Boolean(result.Response) === true) {
            film.omdb.push(result);
        }
        var imdbid = result.imdbID;
        return HttpService.getContent(configExternal.themoviedburl + imdbid + '/videos?api_key=' + configExternal.themoviedbkey);
    }).then(function(data) {
        film.trailers = [];
        film.trailers.push(JSON.parse(data));
    }).catch(function (err) {
        logger.error().info('Error getting ' + film.title + ' from omdb, ErrorMessage : ' + err);
    }));
});

//--------------------------------
// When all promises have finished
//--------------------------------
Promise.all(promises).then(function (data, err) {
    // do stuff with the data
});
```

And here is my getContent func

```
var Service = {
    getContent: function(url) {
        var deferred = q.defer();
        request(url, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                deferred.resolve(body);
            } else {
                deferred.reject(error);
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
};
```

Comment: Promises work by return value, you have a middle `then` that doesn't return _anything_ - in JS when things return nothing they automatically return `undefined`.

Comment: Your promises don't deliver data. Instead, the original `files` are augmented with new properties. All you need to do is change the comment "do stuff with the data" to "do stuff with the files", and write that code block accordingly.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I so what should I return if I have nothing to call?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 i don't get where you are going?

Comment: Sorry, I made two typos. Comment should read, "Your promises don't deliver data. Instead, the original `films` are augmented with new properties. All you need to do is change the comment "do stuff with the data" to "do stuff with the **films**", and write that code block accordingly"

Comment: No because when I hit the second promise it is random if I get that data into each film object. So thats not the case. But thanks for trying

Comment: But yes, nothing is random. As written, the lines `film.omdb.push(result)` and `film.trailers = [];` will address the correct `film`, which is trapped in a closure. It can't go wrong! Therefore change nothing, just write that "do stuff with the films" block correctly.

Comment: Okey I get what you are saying but what I am doing in the Promise.all() is that I I write the films to json file on file system. However since I only push the first request into promises array, then I don't have the wanted trailers data. I am telling you this is not working... Could you give me an example what you guys are thinkning

Comment: @jonjonson, you are misreading your own code. `promises.push(...)` wraps the *entire promise chain* `HttpService.getContent(...).then(function (...) { ...; return HttpService.getContent(...); }).then(function(...) {...;}).catch(function (...) {...})`. Therefore the final promise returned by that chain is what gets pushed onto the `promises` array, taking *both* `.getContent()` asynchronisms into account.

Comment: If it's not working, then it's not overall pattern that's wrong. It must be somewhere in the detail.

Comment: Okey Thank you I'll try to see if I will find any error

Comment: No dont' seem to find the error but thanks anyway. Gurrrrr.... this is frustrating

Comment: Try `console.log(body);` at first line of the callback in `Service.getContent()`. Depending on the outcome, work forwards or backwards from that point to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. There wasn't anything wrong with the request as Roamer said. But the moviedata base limits by 40 request per 10 sek witch I didn't know :)

Comment: Aha! That's a fairly tricky constraint to code for. Try asking another question.